# GetBlobReferenceFromServer not working with relative URIs. Error: "Only absolute addresses are permitted"

Tags: .net, vb.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am upgrading Azure Storage from 1.7 SDK to 2.3 SDK and have been updating my `GetBlobReference(string)` calls to `GetBlockReferenceFromServer(Uri)`

In the past I have been using relative URIs, but when I pass these through to `GetBlockReferenceFromServer`  I get an error that says I cannot use absolute URIs (see stack below)

**Sample code:**

```
Dim myAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString)
Dim myClient As CloudBlobClient = myAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
Dim myRelativeUri As New Uri("mycontainer/myblob.txt", UriKind.Relative)
Dim myBlobref As ICloudBlob = myClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(myRelativeUri) <- Errors on this line
```

**Error stack:**

```
System.ArgumentException: Address 'mycontainer/myblob.txt' is a relative address. Only absolute addresses are permitted.Parameter name: uri   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageUri.AssertAbsoluteUri(Uri uri)   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageUri.set_PrimaryUri(Uri value)   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageUri..ctor(Uri primaryUri, Uri secondaryUri)   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageUri..ctor(Uri primaryUri)   
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobClient.GetBlobReferenceFromServer(Uri blobUri, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)   at MySoftware.MyReference...
```

I don't understand why the Uri has to be absolute when the `CloudBlobClient` has a `BaseUri` to work from.   Do I have to manually prepend the `BaseUri` on before I try to get the reference?

There is nothing in the [technical reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj732165.aspx) about this.

Has anyone got relative URIs to work with `GetBlobReferenceFromServer`?   Is there something that I am fundamentally doing wrong?

Comment: There have been many breaking changes between storage client library version 1.7 and 2.0 (that was the version number when it was released). Seems this was one of them. I tried to look up release notes for 2.0 version (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt) but unfortunately it only starts from 2.0.1. I guess you just have to assume that this was one of the breaking change and you would need to provide absolute URI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. GetBlobReferenceFromServer requires absolute URIs, as it was designed for a specific scenario, where the user just has a URI to the blob and needs to get its blob type to even start working with it.

If you know the type of your blob, I would strongly recommend using GetContainerReference and then GetBlockBlobReference or GetPageBlobReference instead, as these methods do not have to make a call to the Azure Storage Service to get the blob type. Hence, they would reduce cost and increase performance. They also work directly with blob names, not URIs.